# What is C++ comparing when comparing two different strings?

Tags: c++

Code below when I check if K or Y is greater, what method is used to compare two different strings? number of bits?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string y = "can't";
    string k = "solve";

    if(k > y){
        cout << "k is bigger";
    }else {
        cout << "y is bigger";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
k is bigger
```

Comment: alphabetic order?

Comment: How about a [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)?

Comment: It's a lexographical compare

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp

Answer (score 4):

[string compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) is a lexigraphical comparison:

> All comparisons are done via the compare() member function (which
>   itself is defined in terms of Traits::compare()):
>
> Two strings are equal if both the size of lhs and rhs are equal and
>   each character in lhs has equivalent character in rhs at the same
>   position.
>
> The ordering comparisons are done lexicographically -- the comparison
>   is performed by a function equivalent to std::lexicographical_compare.

And this is how lexigraphical comparison works:

> A [lexicographical comparison](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/#targetText=A%20lexicographical%20comparison%20is%20the,not%20equivalent%20to%20the%20other.) is the kind of comparison generally
>   used to sort words alphabetically in dictionaries; It involves
>   comparing sequentially the elements that have the same position in
>   both ranges against each other until one element is not equivalent to
>   the other.

Answer (score 0):

These relational operators are overloaded in the header file string.
All the relational operators used for string operations can be found in the link below.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/

Hope this clears your doubt.